# How can I get the moving std dev of the number of rows in the rolling period, with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this (index is the timestamp, so it is a datetime type):

```
timestamp                price        quantity   direction    aggregated
2020-09-04 00:00:00.000  381.501760     3.000         s        True
2020-09-04 00:00:00.212  381.530000     3.225         s       False
2020-09-04 00:00:00.560  381.346627   207.477         s        True
2020-09-04 00:00:00.590  381.450000     2.586         s       False
2020-09-04 00:00:00.652  381.540000     0.030         b       False
...

**Notice that the timestamps are not evenly spaced.**


I would like to calculate the rolling std dev of the number of rows inside the rolling period.

For example, if I have a period of 300ms, the rolling window would return:

- row 0 returns 1 (itself)
- row 1 returns 2 (itself and row 0 since it's less than 300ms away)
- row 2 returns 1 (itself, row 0 and 1 are more than 300ms away and is not included)
- row 3 returns 2 (itself and row 2 since it's the only one close enough)
- row 4 returns 3 (itself and row 2 and 3 since they're both within 300ms)

and I'd like to get the std dev of that.

How can I calculate this?
```

Comment: did you try [rolling.std](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Window.std.html#pandas.core.window.rolling.Window.std) ?

Comment: @RichieV, but that will not count the number of rows?

Comment: so you want the stdev of `[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: yes, but the question is more how do I make a rolling window that calculate the number of rows fitting in that window as the index is irregular and the window is datetime based

Comment: pseudocode: `np.std( df.price.rolling.count )`

Comment: @RichieV, I didn't know we could do that, yes, it'll work! thanks!

Comment: @Thomas what does the non-pseudocode look like? I got an attribute error.

Comment: order_count_std = (df.rolling(period, min_periods=1).count()).rolling(period, min_periods=1).std()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the count of rows in a window with `rolling.count`. Use it as in:

```
df['rowct_stdev'] = (
    df.price
    .rolling('300ms', min_periods=1).count()
    .rolling('300ms', min_periods=1).std()
)
```

Comment: I need the rolling std dev, so I need to add another .rolling(...) after

Comment: @Thomas sort of a second derivative?

Comment: the first rolling window is to count the elements in the window, the second one is to make a rolling std dev on top